# Rails convert string to array in before_save but display as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm working with emails in a form. Right now it only accepts a single email but we're looking to send multiple emails which means allowing the form to accept multiples.

My thought is do a before_save to convert the emails that are entered into an array and handle sending the emails as an array. The problem is that the form still displays an array. So I have the following in my model:

```
before_save do
 self.email = self.email.split(',').map(&:strip)
end
```

The data converts to an array fine. However the form displays the data as an array and cannot be updated unless it's changed to a string.

The form looks like:

```
=tb_form_for [:admin, @contact], remote: true, data: { errors: :inline, success: thanks_path } do |f|
 = f.tb_text_field :email.to_s
```

But it's actually not converting to a string the array.

Is there another way to accept data as strings, convert to array, and be able to display as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling .to_s, you can convert the array to string with `email.join(',')`, which would convert it to something like `"email a,email b,email c"`

Comment: Tried that. Ended up with undefined method `join'

Comment: @Jake then `email` is not an `Array` and is more likely already a `String` that represents an `Array` e.g. `['me@you.com', 'you@me.com']` is an `Array` but `"[\"me@you.com\",\"you@me.com\"]"` is the `String` representation of the same `Array`. What data type is the `email` field in the database? If this is text (e.g. varchar) then you will have to serialize this data into and out of an `Array` for storage.

Comment: @engineersmnky: what Jake tried is (I suspect): `f.tb_text_field :email.join(',')`. Of course, it doesn't work, even if email is an array.

Comment: Email is set to string.

Comment: @Jake: so the database column is a string? Splitting it in a `before_save` is meaningless then.

Comment: My goal was to allow the form to be present as a string, convert it through a before_save to array, but allow it to be present in the form as a string. Is there a better option than before_save on converting it for the db? Because it's showing in the db as an array (what I want). Just not displaying as a string.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that was a fair bet according the OP but I have a sneaky suspicion that with or without that error this was a bit deeper than that and now I am just confused :)

Comment: @Jake: read engineersmnky's comment again. Your value may _appear_ as an array, but it isn't one. It's a string.

Comment: You don't actually use it as array anywhere, am I correct?

Comment: I'm not using it as an array in anything.

Comment: @Jake: so why are you splitting your string into an array in a before_save? Because a string column won't be able to store an array. Might be better to just store the string as-is and split only when you need the array for presentation/processing/whatever.

Comment: That's....an annoyingly valid point. My plan was to do it for a mailer to send to an array. I guess I can/should just put .split(",").map(&:strip) on the data